# Why doesn't my IBDesignable allow me to use setImage: on my custom UIButton?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, ios8, ibdesignable

In `layoutSubviews` I'm calling `setImage()` and pass it a `UIImage` but it never shows up in Interface Builder, but it always shows up when I run the program.

Answer (score 15):

Probably you are loading your UIImage with this method:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
```

This does not work in interface builder because imageNamed: method uses main bundle but IB loads resources in different way. Try something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image" inBundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
    [self setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Going to give the swift answer for anyone who comes across this problem like I did.

The problem is that paths to images are different in Interface Builder than they are in your app.

```
 let bundle = Bundle(for: self.classForCoder)
 image = UIImage(named: "your_image.png", in: bundle, compatibleWith: self.traitCollection)!
 self.setImage(image, for: .normal)
```